# Interaction between energy and spacetime

Tags: cosmology, big-bang

I hope it's not too stupid but if we say that what we call matter or energy is creating or consuming the spacetime, would not that make the big bang more logical?

Comment: For information about the Big Bang, see [What really happened at the Big Bang?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZdvSJyHvUU). For how matter affects spacetime, see [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a so-called “river model” which describes spacetime as a weird sort of fluid flowing into matter. However, it is very limited. It only works in the Schwarzschild spacetime and the Kerr spacetime. So it would not work for the Big Bang’s FLRW spacetime.

Furthermore, in the spacetimes where it does work, spacetime flows into the matter. It is hard to see how that could be made to work for the Big Bang where you have a whole lot of matter. Naively you would expect the same to be true there, which would oppose expansion rather than explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never heard of this model but thats close to what I have imagined with the extension that start of those rivers is matter too. They both flow out of matter and flow into it thats way I said matter produces and consumes spacetime. please don't ask for an experiment, I'm just thinking out loud

Comment: @omid you cannot just assert that such a model exists. In these models the spacetime literally flows out of nothing and in to the matter. As far as I know there is no model where spacetime flows out of matter, and I think such a model will not work.

Comment: I know there is no such an model but that does not mean I can't imagine one, does it?

Comment: @omid you are free to imagine whatever you like. My comments are not intended to restrict your imagination in any way. I am merely pointing out that there are existing (non-imaginary) models that are close to what you imagine. They indicate that this approach will probably not fare well *outside* of your imagination.

Comment: OK. Personally I can't even think of a model in which "spacetime literally flows out of nothing". It's not logical and I think universe is based on much simpler and cleaner logic than that. thanks for your answer again.

Comment: @omid I agree with you on that. I think that the river model is a pretty poor model. GR itself is substantially cleaner and simpler without the extra baggage of the flow of spacetime

Comment: I know it's a big thing to say but I don't think matter bending spacetime is logical enough too